# Как вывести value в шаблоне thymeleaf в Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Ситуация такая - 
На фронт отдаю `List<String> skills` из профиля пользователя
Необходимо вывести этот список через запятую в качестве value для input поля.

Пробовал следующее -

```
<input id="skills" type="text" class="form-control" name="skills[]" th:value="${#strings.listJoin(#messages.listMsg(currentUser.profile.skills), ',')}" />
```

Проблема -

```
<input id="skills" type="text" class="form-control" name="skills[]" value="??Java_ru??,??PHP_ru??,??JavaScript_ru??">
```

Обратите внимание на `??*_ru??` это происходит потому, что у меня настроена интернационализация и Spring вытается найти строку с такой локализацией.

Другой вариант вывода:

```
<input id="skills" type="text" class="form-control" name="skills[]" th:each="skill, iterStat : ${currentUser.profile.skills}" th:value="!${iterStat.last} ? ${skill} + ',': ${skill}" />
```

В этом случае выводится так:

```
<input id="skills" type="text" class="form-control" name="skills[]" value="Java,">
```

Почему-то он выводит только один тег, вместо 3-х.

В чем может быть ошибка?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
<input id="skills" type="text" class="form-control" name="skills[]" th:value="${#strings.listJoin(currentUser.profile.skills,',')}"/>
```

Так thymeleaf обединяет все поля в одну строку и разделяет запятыми.